# Running single feature test in Laravel with PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I have a Laravel project setup in PhpStorm.  Using **PHP 7.3** with **PHPUnit 8.4.0**.

I have phpunit.xml setup as below, and when I do `Run -> Run -> phpunit.xml` it works fine and all the tests in /tests/feature/ get run...yay.

The output is something like this when it starts:

```
[vagrant:///home/mypc/code/homestead]:/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /home/vagrant/myproject/phpunit.xml --teamcity --cache-result-file=/home/vagrant/myproject/.phpunit.result.cache
```

However I now have lots of tests and I don't always want to run all the tests every time, so I should be able to just right click on any of the test methods and click "Run ...method name...", but when I do an error occurs:

```
[vagrant:///home/mypc/code/homestead]:/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /home/vagrant/myproject/phpunit.xml --filter "/(::test_example_test_for_running)( .*)?$/" Tests\\Feature\\ExampleTest\\ExampleTest /home/vagrant/myproject/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php --teamcity --cache-result-file=/home/vagrant/myproject/.phpunit.result.cache

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Runner\Exception: Class 'Tests\\Feature\\ExampleTest\\ExampleTest' could not be found in '/home/vagrant/myproject/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php'. in /home/vagrant/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:65
```

Here is my phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <extensions>
        <extension class="Tests\Bootstrap"/>
    </extensions>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="APP_CONFIG_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/config.phpunit.php"/>
        <server name="APP_SERVICES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/services.phpunit.php"/>
        <server name="APP_PACKAGES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/packages.phpunit.php"/>
        <server name="APP_ROUTES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/routes.phpunit.php"/>
        <server name="APP_EVENTS_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/events.phpunit.php"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Please try PHPUnit 8.5 and PhpStorm 2019.3.1. Looks the same at first glance: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49132 (P.S. Ignore deprecation warning introduced in PHPUnit 8.5 -- [WI-50201](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50201))

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to **phpunit 8.5** fixed the issue (*Thanks @LazyOne*).

Changed in composer.json:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
```

to:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
```

Then ran `composer update` and everything is working now.